# Retrieving data with the same category from MySQL table to display on a webpage

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hello I have been your follower for quite a while now
I have a very serious problem
I do have a table in mysql database
Table businesses

```
ID. BNAME.  CATEGORY            description
1. Stamp.       Computer        Deals with hardware repair
2. Yastlabc.    Computer       Software and hardware
3. Eastern.        Consultant   General business consulting
4. Goggreen.    Medical         all medical and testing
```

link to  in page A

```
<a href="category.php?id=<?php echo['category'];> "> <?php echo row['category']; ?> </a>
```

code to retrieve data

```
<?php
require 'dbconfig/dbcon.php';
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "select * from business where id=".$id;
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
         $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    }else{
        $errorMsg= 'Could not select record';
    }
}

?>

Results to Display
<h4>

<?php echo $row['bname'];?>
</h4>
<p>

<?php echo $row['description'];?>
</p>
```

when One click the button
it only display data of the specified Id
 The result expected on a page B 
example
category is computer;

```
stamp
Deals with hardware repair

------------------------------------------
Yastlabc
 Software and hardware

-----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I think $row is an array you to use loop to print all data.

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc` fetches only one record out of the result set, you’d need to either do that in a loop, or use `mysqli_fetch_all` to fetch them all in one go. But if you are selecting by ID from this table, you will only ever get one record to begin with. If you want to select all items that have category = computer, you would need to use _that_ in your WHERE clause. You can not select by category via an id, because you do not _have_ any category ids here. (You probably _should_, keyword proper _normalization_.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should loop throw your result set.

```
<?php
require 'dbconfig/dbcon.php';
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "select * from business where id=".$id;
         $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
         echo "Results to Display";
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           echo "<h4>".$row['bname']."</h4>";
           echo "<p>".$row['description']."</p>";
       }
    }else{
        $errorMsg= 'Could not select record';
    }
}

?>
```

remove this part

```
Results to Display
<h4>

<?php echo $row['bname'];?>
</h4>
<p>

<?php echo $row['description'];?>
</p>
```

***NOTE***
there is  problem with your code your querying the database with `$sql = "select * from business where id=".$id;` this will get only single record if the `id = 1` it will get the first record (you are dealing the pk here) .
assuming that your category is unique the query should be like

`"select * from business where category=".$id`

my recommendation to have separate table for the category and use a foreign key on businesses table and your data should look like :

***Table Category***

```
ID    NAME
1     Computer
2     Consultant
3     Medical
```

***Table Businesses***

```
ID. BNAME.  CATEGORY_ID    Description
1. Stamp.       1          Deals with hardware repair
2. Yastlabc.    1          Software and hardware
3. Eastern.     2          General business consulting
4. Goggreen.    3          all medical and testing
```

then the query should look like `"select * from business where category_id=".$id` and the rest of the code is the same.

good luck.